"Do you or she like this elephant?"
Or should the question in the title be "Do you or does she like this elephant?"
In addition, assuming the following ambiguities are independent from the distinction in above phrasings...
Does this question imply the asker knows that at least one of the two referred people "likes this elephant"?
Does this question imply the asker expects that at most one of the two referred people "likes this elephant"?

The question offers no assumptions. I prefer "Do you or does she like it," but one sentence is not required to slice and dice at once. Not even longer: "Do you like this elephant? Does she?"

@Yosef Baskin Just looking at the question itself, it also appears to me that it offers no assumptions. However, when I tried reading it with different stress and pause patterns, it seemed to me either implications could sound "natural".

Words take on different meanings by adding drama. That much is true.

Try to stick to one "question" per question. Altering meaning via stress and intonation seems unrelated to word choice. Meanwhile: please expand on what you mean by "should." In order to appease your own grammatical conscience? In order to sound conversationally informal? In order to be clear?

Re intonation: I could imagine it doing more to affect whether "or" is exclusive or not. I.e., "does X or Y like it" could be "is it liked by any of [X, Y]," or "it's liked by someone; is that person X or is it Y?"

An answer to this question says the verb should agree with the closest pronoun. But there are too many questions here.

I would say "Do either of you like this elephant?"

@KateBunting I agree, a far better way of phrasing it. It may be necessary to ask "Do you or your sister / Susan / that lady like this elephant?" if there is any ambiguity.

@KateBunting Really? I always use singular with either. Does either one of you like this elephant?

@tchrist - I did hesitate between do and does, but decided on do to go with you.

@VincentPhillips I believe that your question has already been answered on our site. Please examine the list of linked questions regarding verb agreement involved with disjunctive subjects. If those do not answer your question, please edit your question to say why they do not.
